# Java Swing Checkboxes in a SplitPane

Tags: java, swing, pane

The current layout I am after is simply a split pane horizonal where on the left side are checkboxes and the right side will be output. I will eventually add a submit button the left side after the user checks all wanted items and I will display the result on the right side. The current issue is that I can't even get the background color to show up and the checkboxes are adding wonky. At certain times I can only see one checkbox in the left panel and I am not sure why, and I also set every container to visible and still not able to see it. I add them in the addBoxes function.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class CheckBox2 extends JFrame {
        private ArrayList<JCheckBox> boxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
        JLabel leftLabel;
        JLabel rightLabel;
        JSplitPane splitPane;

    public CheckBox2() {
         leftLabel = new JLabel();
         rightLabel = new JLabel();

        splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, new JScrollPane(leftLabel), new JScrollPane(rightLabel) );
        leftLabel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        rightLabel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        leftLabel.setVisible(true);
        rightLabel.setVisible(true);
        splitPane.setVisible(true);
        add(splitPane);



    }

    void addBoxes() {
        int i = 0;

        for ( i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) {
            add(new JCheckBox("word" + i ) );
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        CheckBox2 cb = new CheckBox2();
        cb.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        cb.setSize(340, 340);
        cb.setVisible(true);
        cb.addBoxes();
    }



}
```

Comment: Move `cb.setVisible(true);` after `cb.addBoxes();`

Comment: Thanks, so with that I'm just getting the last checkbox, checkbox 9 to show up but it's not giving split screen or showing color :(

Comment: `addBoxes` is just adding the `JCheckBox`s to the `JFrame`, which is using a `BorderLayout` which can only manage a single component at each of its available positions

Answer (score 1):

Start by having a read of [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use Split Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) both which contain plenty of examples.

Swing layouts are lazy.  This means that unless you purposefully trigger a layout pass, any changes won't be reflected on the UI (until a layout pass is triggered, such as resizing the window or making it visible for the first time).

While you can call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container your are changing, in your case, simply calling `setVisible` last will have the same desired effect

> Thanks, so with that I'm just getting the last checkbox, checkbox 9 to show up but it's not giving split screen or showing color :(

That's because `JFrame`, by default, uses a `BorderLayout`, which only allows a single component to be managed at any of the five available positions.  Instead, you need to add you checkboxes to one of the containers in the split pane.

[image: SplitPane and checkboxes]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class CheckBox2 extends JFrame {

  private ArrayList<JCheckBox> boxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
  JSplitPane splitPane;

  private JPanel leftPanel;
  private JPanel rightPanel;

  public CheckBox2() {

    leftPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    rightPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()) {
      @Override
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
      }
    };

    splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, new JScrollPane(rightPanel));
    leftPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    rightPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
    add(splitPane);

    addBoxes();
  }

  void addBoxes() {
    int i = 0;

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      leftPanel.add(new JCheckBox("word" + i), gbc);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    CheckBox2 cb = new CheckBox2();
    cb.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    cb.pack();
    cb.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    cb.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```